# How to pass form data text and file in same request in karate?

Tags: cucumber, karate

I am trying to implement testing for POST request to upload file(image, pdf). My feature file is as follows:

Given path 'files'
* multipart file fileUpl = { read: 'img1.jpeg', filename: 'img1.jpeg' }
* multipart field destination = "posts"
When method post
Then status 200

The file is being picked up correctly but it is not picking up destination field value.

RESPONSE:

Mixed: content-disposition: form-data; name="fileUpl"; filename="img1.jpeg"
content-type: image/jpeg; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 757770
Completed: true
IsInMemory: false
RealFile: /Users/deepanshu/Desktop/NoonCode/nimble/automation/target/test-classes/apiTests/files/img1.jpeg DefaultDeleteAfter: true

**content-disposition: form-data; name="destination"; filename=""
content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8**
content-length: 5
Completed: true
IsInMemory: true

How we can pass on field with values in above case.

Comment: multi-part is hard, so please be prepared to do some research: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68300703/143475